# IE not accepting 3rd party cookies P3P policy setting

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cookies, p3p

I have a site hosted in http://**www.domain1.com**

This domain loads a script located in http://**www.domain2.com/script.js**
This sript is loaded with the normal HTML <script> tag method. This script is setting and reading cookies.

The problem is when I view *domain1* with **IE**, the **cookies for domain2 are not set**. This does not happen in other browsers (FF, chrome, safari).

I tried to fix the issue setting special **P3P headers** returned by the *script.js* without luck.
What I don't understand is, where the *P3P policy* has to be set, in *domain1* or *domain2*?

I don't want to set a policy, I just want my cookies to work. **Which is the easier approach without touching *domain1***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set in domain2 ,without touching domain1

for domain2 ,domain1 is a third-party context.

p3p is used to process this,and it's related to user's client setting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms905230.aspx